# Sending data from one app to another thrid party app

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public void executeApp(ExecuteABCDEvent event) {
    PackageManager pm = this.getContext().getPackageManager();
    try {
        String packageName = "package name here";
        Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

        this.getContext().startActivity(launchIntent);

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.d("Exception", e1.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am opening a 3rd pary application using the above code.
Along with opening of this 3rd party application I also want to populate some text fields.

Solution 1: put and get data from intent.
I cannot user solution 1 as i cannot use the get methods in 3rd party app.

Solution 2: Content provider.I am not sure how content provider of application works and how it helps.

Is there another approach for this.

Comment: Did you write this "3rd party application"?

Comment: In general, you can't do the automatically if the other app doesn't provide support for it.

Comment: Nope... I cannot access its source code and hence cannot go for solution: put and get from one app to another

Answer (score 1):

You have no good way of doing what you want. For obvious security reasons, apps cannot hack into other apps.

You are welcome to create an `AccessibilityService` and attempt to use that to achieve your ends. I am skeptical that it will work, and even if it does, I am skeptical that many people will install your app, given the large security warnings that are presented when the user goes in to activate your `AccessibilityService`.